# Image stretched when I capture image and save to SD card in Android

Tags: android

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opts);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 50, false);
int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();
int newWidth = 150;
int newHeight = 50;

// calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

// createa matrix for the manipulation
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
// resize the bit map
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
// rotate the Bitmap
matrix.postRotate(-90);
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
        width, height, matrix, true);
//      HomePage.image.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Intent in1 = new Intent(CameraView.this, ImageDisplay.class);
in1.putExtra("picture",byteArray);
startActivity(in1);
```

This is my code. I am unable to set image because image becomes stretched. It's not coming clear image full screen. Where am I doing wrong?

My image come like this we have fix it it should not stretched.

[image]

Comment: Do a test. Compress your resizedBitmap to file and display the file with an external app. How does it look yhrn?

Comment: `my code i am unable to set image because image becomes stretched its not `. Should we be able to read such sentences? Please take the time to write in a nkrmal way.

Answer (score 1):

It can be due to 'createScaledBitmap' as may be the image size is small and when you try to resize it it gets streched

You can use this:

```
   public Bitmap compressImage(String imageUri) {

        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

        float maxHeight = 816.0f;
        float maxWidth = 612.0f;
        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return scaledBitmap;

    }
```

Comment: then how to fix it  any suggestion for this please help!

Comment: how to fix this issue any suggestion

Comment: calculateInSampleSize  method is no there @Deepali-Systematix

Comment: I have added another answer for the same.Please check

Answer (score 0):

Code for saving:

```
 FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/camtest");
    dir.mkdirs();
    String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
    File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
    refreshGallery(outFile);
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Finally:

Go to Device Settings>Device>Applications>Application Manager>"your app">Permissions>Enable Storage permission!

Comment: refreshGallery what is this is it any function?

Comment: no i am unable to save and unable to fix streched image issue @kunam Vaja

Answer (score 0):

I have a written a code  to pick image from gallery or capture image from camera  you can use this to achieve what you want and you will get the file path of capture from camera  or picked from gallery  image file path  in onactivityforResult

```
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

private static final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 2;
private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 3;


public static final int camPermissionRequestCode=6;
public static final int galleryPermissionRequestCode=4;

private Uri imageUri;

private File profilePicPicked;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    int id=v.getId();

    switch (id){


        case R.id.camera:
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                //do your check here

                isStoragePermissionGranted(camPermissionRequestCode);

            } else {

                captureImage();

            }

            break;
        case R.id.upload_image:

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                //do your check here
                isStoragePermissionGranted(galleryPermissionRequestCode);

            } else {

                pickFromGallery();

            }


            break;

    }

}





@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
        return;



    switch (requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE:
            /**
             * After taking a picture, do the crop
             */


            File file2 = handleImageUri(imageUri,getContext());


            try {

                ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(file2.getAbsolutePath());
                int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        file2=rotateImage(file2, 90);
                       /* Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"90",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        file2=rotateImage(file2, 180);
                       /* Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"180",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        file2=rotateImage(file2, 270);
                       /* Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"270",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                        /*Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"default",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    default:
                        break;

                }

            }catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            profilePicPicked= file2;


            break;

        case PICK_FROM_FILE:
            /**
             * After selecting image from files, save the selected path
             */

            /*Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
            imageUri = data.getData();

            //iv_post.setImageURI(fileUri);
            File fileGAllr = getRealPathFromURIForGallery(getActivity(),imageUri);

            profilePicPicked=fileGAllr;


            // new Updata().execute("");
            // btn_gallery.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            break;

        case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:

            break;

    }

}



public static File getRealPathFromURIForGallery(Context context, Uri uri) {
    File file = null;
    try {


        String extension="";
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            extension= filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("."));
            System.out.print("");
        }
        cursor.close();

        InputStream input = null;
        input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

        if (input == null) {
            return null;
        }
        file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), System.currentTimeMillis()+"_Photo"+extension);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            output.flush();
        } finally {
            output.close();
            input.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.toString());
    }
    return file;
}




public File  rotateImage(File f, float angle) {

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), options);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);


    Bitmap finalBm= Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    File editedFile=getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(editedFile);
        finalBm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
        // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    f.delete();

    return editedFile;
}


public static File handleImageUri(Uri uri, Context context) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(content://media/.*\\d)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(uri.getPath());
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return getRealPathFromURI(context, uri);
    } else {
        return new File(uri.getPath());
    }
}


public static File getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri uri) {
    File file = null;
    try {
        InputStream input = null;
        input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

        if (input == null) {
            return null;
        }
        file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), System.currentTimeMillis()+"Photo.png");
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            output.flush();
        } finally {
            output.close();
            input.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.toString());
    }
    return file;
}


public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted(int requsetCode) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if(requsetCode==camPermissionRequestCode){

                captureImage();
            }else{

                pickFromGallery();
            }
            return true;
        } else {


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, requsetCode);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation

        if(requsetCode==camPermissionRequestCode){

            captureImage();
        }else{

            pickFromGallery();
        }
        return true;
    }


}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if(requestCode==camPermissionRequestCode){

            captureImage();
        }else if(requestCode==galleryPermissionRequestCode){

            pickFromGallery();
        }
        //resume tasks needing this permission
    }
}



private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    imageUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}


private void pickFromGallery(){

    Intent i = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, PICK_FROM_FILE);
}


public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}


private File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "marcopolo");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {

            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: and i am handling the orientation issue as well .. as on some devices the orientation of image is rotated while we capture image from camera

Answer (score 0):

```
>       public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight){
>             final int height = options.outHeight;
>             final int width = options.outWidth;
>             int inSampleSize = 1;
>             if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
>                 final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
>                 inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;}
>             final float totalPixels = width * height;
>             final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;
>             while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {inSampleSize++;}
>             return inSampleSize;}
>     
>     > `Blockquote`
```